# Web scraping table gives correct reading from wrong data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this table from [ESPN Neo York Knicks 2019](http://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/ny/season/2019),however from site the data is different from is actually being scraped[image]

So after making sure i am doing it correctly and searching other sites for actual dates it appears the data i am scraping is correct but the value on displayed ESPN is wrong !?

Here is my code:

```
import requests,bs4,re,time,random
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}
url="http://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/ny/season/2019"
req=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")
table=soup.find("tbody",{"class":"Table2__tbody"})
x=table.find_all("tr")
dates=[]
for i in x:
    try:
        regex2=re.search('(\w\w\w, \w\w\w \d+)vs.*',i.text).groups() #date=Wed, Oct 17 from where??
        #print(i.text)
        dates.append(regex2[0])
    except AttributeError:
        pass
y=table.find_all(class_="Table2__td")
links=[]
for i in y:
    if i.find("a",href=True):
        temp = i.find("a", href=True)
        #print(temp['href'])
        if "gameId" in temp['href']:
            links.append(temp['href'])
print(dates)
dictionary = dict(zip(dates, links))
print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
['Wed, Oct 17', 'Sat, Oct 20', 'Fri, Oct 26', 'Mon, Oct 29', 'Wed, Oct 31', 'Mon, Nov 5', 'Sun, Nov 11', 'Tue, Nov 20', 'Fri, Nov 23', 'Sat, Dec 1', 'Mon, Dec 3', 'Sat, Dec 8', 'Sun, Dec 9', 'Mon, Dec 17', 'Fri, Dec 21', 'Tue, Dec 25', 'Fri, Jan 11', 'Sun, Jan 13', 'Thu, Jan 17', 'Mon, Jan 21', 'Wed, Jan 23', 'Sun, Jan 27', 'Wed, Jan 30', 'Fri, Feb 1', 'Sun, Feb 3', 'Tue, Feb 5', 'Sat, Feb 9', 'Wed, Feb 13', 'Fri, Feb 22', 'Sun, Feb 24', 'Tue, Feb 26', 'Thu, Feb 28', 'Sat, Mar 9', 'Sun, Mar 17', 'Wed, Mar 20', 'Fri, Mar 22', 'Sun, Mar 24', 'Thu, Mar 28', 'Sat, Mar 30', 'Mon, Apr 1', 'Sun, Apr 7', 'Wed, Apr 10']
{'Wed, Oct 17': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070697', 'Sat, Oct 20': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070704', 'Fri, Oct 26': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070711', 'Mon, Oct 29': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070723', 'Wed, Oct 31': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070735', 'Mon, Nov 5': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070749', 'Sun, Nov 11': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070771', 'Tue, Nov 20': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070786', 'Fri, Nov 23': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070802', 'Sat, Dec 1': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070816', 'Mon, Dec 3': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070824', 'Sat, Dec 8': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070836', 'Sun, Dec 9': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070855', 'Mon, Dec 17': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070867', 'Fri, Dec 21': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070890', 'Tue, Dec 25': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070903', 'Fri, Jan 11': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070917', 'Sun, Jan 13': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070932', 'Thu, Jan 17': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070936', 'Mon, Jan 21': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070950', 'Wed, Jan 23': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070972', 'Sun, Jan 27': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070982', 'Wed, Jan 30': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070988', 'Fri, Feb 1': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071011', 'Sun, Feb 3': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071027', 'Tue, Feb 5': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071046', 'Sat, Feb 9': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071063', 'Wed, Feb 13': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071071', 'Fri, Feb 22': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071087', 'Sun, Feb 24': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071102', 'Tue, Feb 26': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071119', 'Thu, Feb 28': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071125', 'Sat, Mar 9': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071138', 'Sun, Mar 17': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071153', 'Wed, Mar 20': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401070233', 'Fri, Mar 22': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071189', 'Sun, Mar 24': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071208', 'Thu, Mar 28': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071227', 'Sat, Mar 30': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071250', 'Mon, Apr 1': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071273', 'Sun, Apr 7': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071281', 'Wed, Apr 10': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401071299'}
```

Comment: interesting. The scraping gives the other days of the week.

Comment: @QHarr what is even more interesting is if i open page with proxy from USA it gives the correct reading, from Japan this reading :D

Comment: use selenium with proxy?

Comment: @QHarr VPN with selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of what day it was when the game took place in a given timezone. It looks like the site renders the dates relative to the tz you're making the request from, which based on your comments appears to be either somewhere in the USA or Japan. The large gap between these can result in different days being displayed.

For example, the first game took place on 2018-10-17 @ 7:30pm in New York, where the timezone is `UTC-4`. But that time [equates](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20181017T233000&p1=179&p2=248) to 2018-10-18 @ 8:30am in Tokyo, where the it's `UTC+9`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data by the class name of the `tbody`:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/ny/season/2019').text, 'html.parser')
header, *results = [[i.text for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in d.find_all('tr', {'class':re.compile('^Table2__tr')})]
final_data = [dict(zip(header, i)) for i in results]
```

Output:

```
[{'Date': 'Wed, Oct 17', 'Opponent': 'vs Atlanta ', 'Result': 'W126-107  ', 'W-L': '1-0', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  31', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  11', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  5'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Oct 19', 'Opponent': '@ Brooklyn ', 'Result': 'L107-105  ', 'W-L': '1-1', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  29', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  4'}, {'Date': 'Sat, Oct 20', 'Opponent': 'vs Boston ', 'Result': 'L103-101  ', 'W-L': '1-2', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  24', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  15', 'Hi Assists': 'Burke  9'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Oct 22', 'Opponent': '@ Milwaukee ', 'Result': 'L124-113  ', 'W-L': '1-3', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  24', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  13', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  5'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Oct 24', 'Opponent': '@ Miami ', 'Result': 'L110-87  ', 'W-L': '1-4', 'Hi Points': 'Dotson  20', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Dotson  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  5'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Oct 26', 'Opponent': 'vs Golden State ', 'Result': 'L128-100  ', 'W-L': '1-5', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  24', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  13', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  4'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Oct 29', 'Opponent': 'vs Brooklyn ', 'Result': 'W115-96  ', 'W-L': '2-5', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  25', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  15', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  8'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Oct 31', 'Opponent': 'vs Indiana ', 'Result': 'L107-101  ', 'W-L': '2-6', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  37', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  7'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Nov 2', 'Opponent': '@ Dallas ', 'Result': 'W118-106  ', 'W-L': '3-6', 'Hi Points': 'Trier  23', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Robinson  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  7'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Nov 4', 'Opponent': '@ Washington ', 'Result': 'L108-95  ', 'W-L': '3-7', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  18', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  12', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  4'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Nov 5', 'Opponent': 'vs Chicago ', 'Result': 'L116-115 2OT ', 'W-L': '3-8', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  23', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  24', 'Hi Assists': 'Kanter  7'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Nov 7', 'Opponent': '@ Atlanta ', 'Result': 'W112-107  ', 'W-L': '4-8', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  34', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  13', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  3'}, {'Date': 'Sat, Nov 10', 'Opponent': '@ Toronto ', 'Result': 'L128-112  ', 'W-L': '4-9', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  27', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  15', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  4'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Nov 11', 'Opponent': 'vs Orlando ', 'Result': 'L115-89  ', 'W-L': '4-10', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  17', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  15', 'Hi Assists': 'Burke  5'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Nov 14', 'Opponent': '@ Oklahoma City ', 'Result': 'L128-103  ', 'W-L': '4-11', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  20', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Hezonja  6', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  5'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Nov 16', 'Opponent': '@ New Orleans ', 'Result': 'L129-124  ', 'W-L': '4-12', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  30', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Hardaway Jr.  8', 'Hi Assists': 'Trier  5'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Nov 18', 'Opponent': '@ Orlando ', 'Result': 'L131-117  ', 'W-L': '4-13', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  32', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  19', 'Hi Assists': 'Kanter  3'}, {'Date': 'Tue, Nov 20', 'Opponent': 'vs Portland ', 'Result': 'L118-114  ', 'W-L': '4-14', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  32', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Kanter  6'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Nov 21', 'Opponent': '@ Boston ', 'Result': 'W117-109  ', 'W-L': '5-14', 'Hi Points': 'Burke  29', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Burke  11'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Nov 23', 'Opponent': 'vs New Orleans ', 'Result': 'W114-109  ', 'W-L': '6-14', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  27', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  11', 'Hi Assists': 'Vonleh  5'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Nov 25', 'Opponent': '@ Memphis ', 'Result': 'W103-98  ', 'W-L': '7-14', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  22', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  26', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  4'}, {'Date': 'Tue, Nov 27', 'Opponent': '@ Detroit ', 'Result': 'L115-108  ', 'W-L': '7-15', 'Hi Points': 'Trier  24', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Trier  7'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Nov 28', 'Opponent': '@ Philadelphia ', 'Result': 'L117-91  ', 'W-L': '7-16', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  17', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Knox  7', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  3'}, {'Date': 'Sat, Dec 1', 'Opponent': 'vs Milwaukee ', 'Result': 'W136-134 OT ', 'W-L': '8-16', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  28', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  7', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  8'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Dec 3', 'Opponent': 'vs Washington ', 'Result': 'L110-107  ', 'W-L': '8-17', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  20', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  16', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  4'}, {'Date': 'Thu, Dec 6', 'Opponent': '@ Boston ', 'Result': 'L128-100  ', 'W-L': '8-18', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  22', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  11', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  6'}, {'Date': 'Sat, Dec 8', 'Opponent': 'vs Brooklyn ', 'Result': 'L112-104  ', 'W-L': '8-19', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  23', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  4'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Dec 9', 'Opponent': 'vs Charlotte ', 'Result': 'L119-107  ', 'W-L': '8-20', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  26', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Knox  15', 'Hi Assists': 'Vonleh  9'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Dec 12', 'Opponent': '@ Cleveland ', 'Result': 'L113-106  ', 'W-L': '8-21', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  20', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  7'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Dec 14', 'Opponent': '@ Charlotte ', 'Result': 'W126-124 OT ', 'W-L': '9-21', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  34', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  11', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  8'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Dec 16', 'Opponent': '@ Indiana ', 'Result': 'L110-99  ', 'W-L': '9-22', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  20', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  15', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  6'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Dec 17', 'Opponent': 'vs Phoenix ', 'Result': 'L128-110  ', 'W-L': '9-23', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  32', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  6'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Dec 19', 'Opponent': '@ Philadelphia ', 'Result': 'L131-109  ', 'W-L': '9-24', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  27', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  5'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Dec 21', 'Opponent': 'vs Atlanta ', 'Result': 'L114-107  ', 'W-L': '9-25', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  32', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  5'}, {'Date': 'Tue, Dec 25', 'Opponent': 'vs Milwaukee ', 'Result': 'L109-95  ', 'W-L': '9-26', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  21', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  5'}, {'Date': 'Thu, Dec 27', 'Opponent': '@ Milwaukee ', 'Result': 'L112-96  ', 'W-L': '9-27', 'Hi Points': 'Kornet  23', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  13', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  6'}, {'Date': 'Sat, Dec 29', 'Opponent': '@ Utah ', 'Result': 'L129-97  ', 'W-L': '9-28', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  18', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  9', 'Hi Assists': 'Kornet  5'}, {'Date': 'Tue, Jan 1', 'Opponent': '@ Denver ', 'Result': 'L115-108  ', 'W-L': '9-29', 'Hi Points': 'Kornet  19', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  9'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Jan 4', 'Opponent': '@ Los Angeles ', 'Result': 'W119-112  ', 'W-L': '10-29', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  22', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  15', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  6'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Jan 7', 'Opponent': '@ Portland ', 'Result': 'L111-101  ', 'W-L': '10-30', 'Hi Points': 'Kanter  18', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  7'}, {'Date': 'Tue, Jan 8', 'Opponent': '@ Golden State ', 'Result': 'L122-95  ', 'W-L': '10-31', 'Hi Points': 'Hezonja  19', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Kanter  16', 'Hi Assists': 'Mudiay  4'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Jan 11', 'Opponent': 'vs Indiana ', 'Result': 'L121-106  ', 'W-L': '10-32', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  21', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Thomas  7', 'Hi Assists': 'Dotson  4'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Jan 13', 'Opponent': 'vs Philadelphia ', 'Result': 'L108-105  ', 'W-L': '10-33', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  31', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Knox  7', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  6'}, {'Date': 'Thu, Jan 17', 'Opponent': 'vs Washington *', 'Result': 'L101-100  ', 'W-L': '10-34', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  25', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Trier  3'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Jan 21', 'Opponent': 'vs Oklahoma City ', 'Result': 'L127-109  ', 'W-L': '10-35', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  23', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Trier  6', 'Hi Assists': 'Trier  8'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Jan 23', 'Opponent': 'vs Houston ', 'Result': 'L114-110  ', 'W-L': '10-36', 'Hi Points': 'Trier  31', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Trier  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Ntilikina  6'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Jan 25', 'Opponent': '@ Brooklyn ', 'Result': 'L109-99  ', 'W-L': '10-37', 'Hi Points': 'Burke  25', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  13', 'Hi Assists': 'Burke  5'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Jan 27', 'Opponent': 'vs Miami ', 'Result': 'L106-97  ', 'W-L': '10-38', 'Hi Points': 'Hardaway Jr.  22', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  9', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  5'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Jan 28', 'Opponent': '@ Charlotte ', 'Result': 'L101-92  ', 'W-L': '10-39', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  19', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  12', 'Hi Assists': 'Hardaway Jr.  4'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Jan 30', 'Opponent': 'vs Dallas ', 'Result': 'L114-90  ', 'W-L': '10-40', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  17', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Robinson  7', 'Hi Assists': 'Burke  3'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Feb 1', 'Opponent': 'vs Boston ', 'Result': 'L113-99  ', 'W-L': '10-41', 'Hi Points': 'Dotson  22', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  11', 'Hi Assists': 'Vonleh  7'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Feb 3', 'Opponent': 'vs Memphis ', 'Result': 'L96-84  ', 'W-L': '10-42', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  17', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Jordan  12', 'Hi Assists': 'Smith Jr.  6'}, {'Date': 'Tue, Feb 5', 'Opponent': 'vs Detroit ', 'Result': 'L105-92  ', 'W-L': '10-43', 'Hi Points': 'Smith Jr.  25', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Robinson  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Smith Jr.  6'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Feb 8', 'Opponent': '@ Detroit ', 'Result': 'L120-103  ', 'W-L': '10-44', 'Hi Points': 'Smith Jr.  31', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Jordan  11', 'Hi Assists': 'Smith Jr.  8'}, {'Date': 'Sat, Feb 9', 'Opponent': 'vs Toronto ', 'Result': 'L104-99  ', 'W-L': '10-45', 'Hi Points': 'Knox  20', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Jordan  18', 'Hi Assists': 'Allen  6'}, {'Date': 'Mon, Feb 11', 'Opponent': '@ Cleveland ', 'Result': 'L107-104  ', 'W-L': '10-46', 'Hi Points': 'Allen  25', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Jordan  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Allen  6'}, {'Date': 'Wed, Feb 13', 'Opponent': 'vs Philadelphia ', 'Result': 'L126-111  ', 'W-L': '10-47', 'Hi Points': 'Trier  19', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Robinson  13', 'Hi Assists': 'Jordan  7'}, {'Date': 'Thu, Feb 14', 'Opponent': '@ Atlanta ', 'Result': 'W106-91  ', 'W-L': '11-47', 'Hi Points': 'Smith Jr.  19', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Jordan  13', 'Hi Assists': 'Allen  9'}, {'Date': 'Fri, Feb 22', 'Opponent': 'vs Minnesota ', 'Result': 'L115-104  ', 'W-L': '11-48', 'Hi Points': 'Dotson  20', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Jordan  19', 'Hi Assists': 'Smith Jr.  7'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Feb 24', 'Opponent': 'vs San Antonio ', 'Result': 'W130-118  ', 'W-L': '12-48', 'Hi Points': 'Dotson  27', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Robinson  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Smith Jr.  13'}, {'Date': 'Tue, Feb 26', 'Opponent': 'vs Orlando ', 'Result': 'W108-103  ', 'W-L': '13-48', 'Hi Points': 'Mudiay  19', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Robinson  14', 'Hi Assists': 'Ellenson  5'}, {'Date': 'Thu, Feb 28', 'Opponent': 'vs Cleveland ', 'Result': 'L125-118  ', 'W-L': '13-49', 'Hi Points': 'Trier  22', 'Hi Rebounds': 'Vonleh  10', 'Hi Assists': 'Smith Jr.  8'}, {'Date': 'Date', 'Opponent': 'Opponent', 'Result': 'Time', 'W-L': 'TV', 'Hi Points': 'tickets'}, {'Date': 'Sun, Mar 3', 'Opponent': '@ LA ', 'Result': '3:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '1,335 tickets as low as $13 '}, {'Date': 'Mon, Mar 4', 'Opponent': '@ Sacramento ', 'Result': '10:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '1,066 tickets as low as $12 '}, {'Date': 'Wed, Mar 6', 'Opponent': '@ Phoenix ', 'Result': '9:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '1,950 tickets as low as $10 '}, {'Date': 'Sat, Mar 9', 'Opponent': 'vs Sacramento ', 'Result': '12:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,414 tickets as low as $62 '}, {'Date': 'Sun, Mar 10', 'Opponent': '@ Minnesota ', 'Result': '8:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '609 tickets as low as $26 '}, {'Date': 'Tue, Mar 12', 'Opponent': '@ Indiana ', 'Result': '7:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,603 tickets as low as $5 '}, {'Date': 'Fri, Mar 15', 'Opponent': '@ San Antonio ', 'Result': '8:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,606 tickets as low as $13 '}, {'Date': 'Sun, Mar 17', 'Opponent': 'vs Los Angeles ', 'Result': '12:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,825 tickets as low as $202 '}, {'Date': 'Mon, Mar 18', 'Opponent': '@ Toronto ', 'Result': '7:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '1,685 tickets as low as $32 '}, {'Date': 'Wed, Mar 20', 'Opponent': 'vs Utah ', 'Result': '7:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,920 tickets as low as $39 '}, {'Date': 'Fri, Mar 22', 'Opponent': 'vs Denver ', 'Result': '7:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '3,003 tickets as low as $46 '}, {'Date': 'Sun, Mar 24', 'Opponent': 'vs LA ', 'Result': '12:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '3,001 tickets as low as $44 '}, {'Date': 'Thu, Mar 28', 'Opponent': 'vs Toronto ', 'Result': '7:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,775 tickets as low as $56 '}, {'Date': 'Sat, Mar 30', 'Opponent': 'vs Miami ', 'Result': '7:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,761 tickets as low as $59 '}, {'Date': 'Mon, Apr 1', 'Opponent': 'vs Chicago ', 'Result': '7:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,770 tickets as low as $36 '}, {'Date': 'Wed, Apr 3', 'Opponent': '@ Orlando ', 'Result': '7:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,123 tickets as low as $17 '}, {'Date': 'Fri, Apr 5', 'Opponent': '@ Houston ', 'Result': '8:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,498 tickets as low as $13 '}, {'Date': 'Sun, Apr 7', 'Opponent': 'vs Washington ', 'Result': '7:30 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,746 tickets as low as $49 '}, {'Date': 'Tue, Apr 9', 'Opponent': '@ Chicago ', 'Result': '8:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '3,493 tickets as low as $19 '}, {'Date': 'Wed, Apr 10', 'Opponent': 'vs Detroit ', 'Result': '8:00 PM ', 'W-L': '', 'Hi Points': '2,132 tickets as low as $57 '}]
```

Comment: Hey,My question was actually on why is the data displayed "wrong" on site,but when scraped it "correct" , I hope you understand my question.